# How to find out a file belongs to which package in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, macports, homebrew

Is there a way to find out which Application / package owns or creates a specific file? For example, in Linux these commands will show the package owner

```
apt-file /bin/progname

rpm -qf /bin/progname

yum whatprovides /bin/progname
```

In OS X, a file could be part of a native OS X application, or installed by Macports or Homebrew. These are completely different environments. Are there commands for each environment to check which application / package owns a specific file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a little late, but perhaps it will be of help to others.

You can use the `pkgutil` command.

For example, if you want to know what package the "less" command belongs to run:

`pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/less`

Which will output something like:

```
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/less

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemBinaries
pkg-version: 10.7.0.1.1.1309742044
install-time: 1310407891
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
```

To list all files contained in a package, `com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemBinaries` in our example, run:

`pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemBinaries`

I know this tool has been present since OS X 10.6.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. You can even use it with GUI applications. Try `pkgutil --file-info /Applications/TextEdit.app`, and you'll get  that it belongs to com.apple.pkg.Essentials, but will also tell you which updaters have been applied to it (in my case, com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.10.2.14C109.patch, com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.10.3.14D131.delta, com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.9.2.13C64.combo).

Comment: doesn't work for me on Big Sur 11.4. `pkgutil --file-info less` just tells me `volume: /` and `path: less`. For other packages, it also just displays the volume and path info, but I can't get the package id, and can't get to the files

Answer (score 8):

This is not really possible since there's no standardized package management.

Unless you configured MacPorts or Homebrew differently, you'll always find their executables in a location that nobody else uses. Since MacPorts and Homebrew do not run under a separate user account, the files they create will always be owned by your user or `root`.

What's left is that you can only try to guess based on the executable location. Here are some rules:

- MacPorts uses `/opt/local/bin` and `/opt/local/sbin` for executables, everything prefixed under `/opt/local`.
- Homebrew uses `/usr/local/bin` for executables, everything else under `/usr/local/`.
- Other applications should create their own directories somewhere under `/usr`, e.g. `/usr/local/git/bin` for the Git OS X installer or `/usr/X11/bin` for X11.
- Some system frameworks symlink to `/usr/bin`, e.g. `rake` points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework`
- No application should ever use `/bin` or `/sbin`. No third party application (i.e. anything not an OS X framework) should use `/usr/bin` either.

Comment: It's not true there's no standardized package management. Mac OS X installs almost all software from packages (using the Installer) and keepsa record. See answer from @bhavin.

Comment: You're right. I was more talking about the programs which might not use standard packages. Didn't know much about pkgutil when I wrote this answer.

Comment: I didn't know about `pkgutil` either, and it sounds pretty handy.

Comment: With MacPorts, you can find out which port owns a particular file using `port provides FILE`

Answer (score 6):

To collect them in one place for the two other package managers on OSX:

For **MacPorts** (as mentioned by Neil in comments above):

```
port provides /opt/local/bin/progname
```

For **Brew** it's not so simple but one can usually find the package using:

```
ls -la /usr/local/bin/progname
```

Which should show a softlink that contains the package name, or else one can use other suggestions from [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915683/how-to-find-package-for-installed-file-in-brew) of these [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/781693/how-to-determine-which-brew-package-provides-a-given-file).

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460320/1959808