# How to determine which brew package provides a given file?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Is there a way to figure out which `brew` package provides a given file (like `apt-file` on Ubuntu or `pkgfile` / `pacman -F` on Arch)?

I'm not talking about querying which locally installed package owns a file on my system, I have a particular file that I need installed (`/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib` to be specific) and want to know which remote package would provide that file.

Comment: Turns out that file is provided by `boost` as long as you configure it with `--with-python`. Would still be nice to know if there was a way to query which files are provided by which files...

Comment: FWIW this is now provided by `boost-python` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not. Nothing in Homebrew maintains a list of files that a package is allowed or expected to install.

Answer (score 16):

As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20040445/695332) you can do `ls -l /usr/local//lib/whatever` and see where the symlink points to.

Comment: Or `ls -l $(which somecommand)`

Answer (score 9):

Though there isn't a built-in `brew` command to search for a specific file, you can use a combination of `brew list` and `brew list <formula>` to get the answer. It takes a while, but if you're doing some cleanup and have to answer this kind of query more than once, you might do what I have done sometimes: make a catalog of files by package:

```
#!/bin/sh
# make a catalog of Homebrew-installed packages by package
brew list --formula |\
  while read formula; do
    brew list $formula |\
    while read file; do
      echo -e "$formula\t$file" # need -e to expand \t
    done
done
```

If you redirect the output of this script to a file, you can use it to search for the package that provides the file of interest.

Comment: This is good, but it searches currently installed packages. The question is asking about searching packages *not* installed.

Comment: I like this. FWIW, brew now issues a warning: `Warning: Calling brew list to only list formulae is deprecated! Use brew list --formula instead.`

Answer (score 5):

While there is not *apt-search* like tool that allows one to find public homebrew packages that could provide a file, many brew packages are based on a linux or unix counterpart. You can search the Debian package website to find the needed package.

Example for finding package that provides file *goocanvas.pc*

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=goocanvas.pc

Returns *libgoocanvas-dev*

`brew search` has no results for *libgoocanvas-dev* or *libgoocanvas* but it does have a *goocanvas* package.

You can define a command `ineed` as follows that would return a list from debian.org using `ineed goocanvas.pc`:

```sh
ineed() {
echo -en $(echo \
    $(curl -s "https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=$1") \
       | sed 's%</*tr>%\\n%g') \
    | grep 'class="file"' \
    | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' \
    | column -t \
    | grep --color -i -w "$1"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the one-liner I have in my `bin` directory for exactly this purpose:

```
$ cat ~/bin/brewpkg

#!/bin/bash
which -s $1 ; if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then ls -lF `which $1` | sed -n 's/^.*\/Cellar\/\([^\/]\{1,\}\)\/.*$/\1/ p' ; fi
```

Comment: Downvoting is of course fine. But it is even more fine if it is supported with a comment explaining the reasons.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but one limitation of this method is that it only finds executables, and can't identify things that don't have executables, e.g., a python module.